# Linux custom compilation fails with Error

Tags: linux, configuration, makefile

I have downloaded latest linux source and am trying to compile but it fails with following error

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `kernel/groups.o', needed by `kernel/built-in.o'.  Stop.
make: *** [kernel] Error 2
```

I tried it on base of Ubuntu14.04 as well as rhel7 but got the same error.
on a bit of googling found out that this was entered as bug for rhel earlier which they responded to saying "we cannot support each configuration"

I tried this with make defconfig, localmodconfig menuconfig but to no avail.

what should be the configuration that would avoid this error..?
anyone able to compile and build linux4.3 on i386..?

EDIT AFTER COMMENTS

I downloaded freshly from the link u gave,

> 1.make mrproper localmodconfig
>   2.make 
>   3.make modules
>   4. make modules_install
>   5.make install /getting error in this step

```
[root@bay16 linux-4.4]# make install
sh ./arch/x86/boot/install.sh 4.4.0 arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
                System.map "/boot"
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module ipt_MASQUERADE
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module iptable_nat
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module nf_nat
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module freq_table
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module power_meter
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module microcode
```

Comment: The latest stable Linux kernel is 4.4, not 4.3: https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.4.tar.xz. I just compiled the `defconfig` and it worked like a charm: `wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.4.tar.xz; tar xf linux-4.4.tar.xz; cd linux-4.4; make mrproper defconfig all`. Tell us a bit more about how you proceeded.

Comment: `ERROR: modinfo: could not find module ipt_MASQUERADE` - such messages at `make install` stage means that *system* **requires** the module for correct booting/working, but the module is not installed for your kernel. You need to modify your configuration so the module is built.